# javaを使ってhtmlにコードを埋め込むには、どうするのが適切か？

Tags: php, java, html

phpでは、htmlに`<p><?= $hello; ?></p>`のような形で埋め込むことができますが、javaを使って同じことをする場合、どのように行えばいいのでしょうか？

詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0105/11/news003.html とか http://www.wakhok.ac.jp/~tomoharu/web2004/text/index_c2.html とかを読んでみて下さい。

Answer (score 2):

一番手軽なものにJSPがございます。
おそらくphpに最もイメージが近いでしょう。

補足ですがJavaでWebアプリケーションを作る場合は、JSPだけで構築することはせず、JSPはHTMLの出力のみに任せて、

- サーブレットと組み合わせる
- 各種フレームワークを利用する

などが良いでしょう。

JavaのWebアプリケーションの構築については、さまざまな書籍やインターネットの記事に情報がございます。例えば以下のサイトで完結にまとまっておりますので、参考にしてはいかがでしょうか。

http://www.techscore.com/tech/Java/JavaEE/index/